# Shadows using Point Light

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a car garage area and I have placed a point light to give lighting and shadows for all objects of the garage area.

[image]

I can able to get lights but there are no shadows, I hope you can see in the above screenshot. Here you have light inspector data:
[image]

In the same scene, there is a Directional Light too and it can able to generate shadows too. But I want to use only Point Light for my garage area so I have created a separate layer for this.

After this Point Light can't able to generate shadows but Direction Light can able to show shadows in the Garage area too that I have checked.
Now guide me to display shadows using Point Light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can able to find help from Unity Forum member.

If you have directional light exist and you are also using other types of lights in the same scene then you have to increase Pixel Light Count figure in Rendering section, I have 0 over there and now I set to 1 and now I can able to get shadow over my garage area.

[image]

This is the exact reply from the right person:
[image]

I hope this reply become useful to other members.